# Camera center calculation with rotation matrix and translate vector

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, geometry, computer-science

What I am trying to do is:

1. generate multiple camera locations along three circle routes at different heights, while cameras only rotate in Yaw angle(always facing center)
2. calculate each camera center's rotation matrix and translate vector
3. verify if they were correct by calculating  `C = -R^T t` to see if the camera locations are the same

But it ends up with different camera locations...

**The followings are my code:**

## Initial settings

```
theta = 10
n = int(360/theta)
circles = 3
r = 10
height = 3
pi = math.pi
alpha = 0
beta = 0
```

## Generate initial camera center

```
for m in range(circles):
    for i in range(n):
        a = np.array([[r*math.cos(2*pi/n*i)], [r*math.sin(2*pi/n*i)], [height*m]], dtype = float)
        if i < 1:
            b = a
        else:
            b = np.hstack((b,a))
    if m < 1:
        c = b
    else:
        c = np.hstack((c,b))

X = c[0,:]
Y = c[1,:]
Z = c[2,:]

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='k')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

which show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY7ky.png)

## Verify if Ratation matrix and Translate vector of each camera are correct

```
for m in range(circles):
    for i in range(n):

        gamma = 0.5*pi + (2*pi/n)*i

        r11 = math.cos(beta)*math.cos(alpha)
        r12 = math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(beta)*math.sin(gamma) - math.cos(gamma)*math.sin(alpha)
        r13 = math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(beta)*math.cos(gamma) + math.sin(alpha)*math.sin(gamma)
        r21 = math.cos(beta)*math.sin(alpha)
        r22 = math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(beta)*math.sin(gamma) + math.cos(alpha)*math.cos(gamma)
        r23 = math.sin(alpha)*math.sin(beta)*math.cos(gamma) - math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(gamma)
        r31 = -math.sin(beta)       
        r32 = math.cos(beta)*math.sin(gamma)          
        r33 = math.cos(beta)*math.cos(gamma)

        Ra = np.array([[r11, r12, r13], [r21, r22, r23], [r31, r32, r33]], dtype = float)

        if i < 1:
            Rb = Ra
        else:
            Rb = np.hstack((Rb,Ra))
    if m < 1:
        Rc = Rb
    else:
        Rc = np.hstack((Rc,Rb))

t = -c

for k in range(n*circles):
    e0 = (Rc[:, 3*k:3*(k+1)].T).dot(t[:, [k]])
    if k < 1:
        e = e0
    else:
        e = np.hstack((e,e0))    

X = e[0,:]
Y = e[1,:]
Z = e[2,:]

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='k')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

But it show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrjE.png), or from [different angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDGsg.png)

What goes wrong during the process? Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a rough answer by changing a few items:

1 Yaw angle is "alpha" instead of "gamma"

2 changed the formula of some "rij" of the matrix "Ra"

3 calculation of "e0" with "Rc" instead of its transpose.

4 The Yaw is just "0.5*pi": the rotation is the same for each point.

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi, cos, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


theta = 10
n = int(360/theta)
circles = 3
r = 10
height = 3
gamma = 0
beta = 0

for m in range(circles):
    for i in range(n):

        a = np.array([[r*cos(2*pi/n*i)],
                      [r*sin(2*pi/n*i)],
                      [height*m]], dtype=float)
        
        if i < 1:
            b = a
        else:
            b = np.hstack((b, a))
    
    if m < 1:
        c = b
    else:
        c = np.hstack((c, b))

X = c[0, :]
Y = c[1, :]
Z = c[2, :]

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='k')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.title("1st Plot")
#plt.draw()
plt.show()

for m in range(circles):
    for i in range(n):

        alpha = 0.5*pi

        r11 = cos(beta)*cos(alpha)
        r12 = cos(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma) - cos(gamma)*sin(alpha)
        r13 = cos(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(alpha)*sin(gamma)
        r21 = cos(beta)*sin(alpha)
        r22 = sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma) + cos(alpha)*cos(gamma)
        r23 = sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma) - cos(alpha)*sin(gamma)
        r31 = -sin(beta)       
        r32 = cos(beta)*sin(gamma)          
        r33 = cos(beta)*cos(gamma)

        Ra = np.array([[r11, r12, r13],
                       [r21, r22, r23],
                       [r31, r32, r33]], dtype=float)

        if i < 1:
            Rb = Ra
        else:
            Rb = np.hstack((Rb, Ra))

    if m < 1:
        Rc = Rb
    else:
        Rc = np.hstack((Rc, Rb))

t = -c

for k in range(n*circles):
    e0 = Rc[:, 3*k:3*(k+1)].dot(t[:, [k]])
    if k < 1:
        e = e0
    else:
        e = np.hstack((e, e0))    

X = e[0, :]
Y = e[1, :]
Z = e[2, :]

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='b')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.title("2nd Plot")
#plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forget to delete part of the formula after the modification.  Aside from that, although the camera locations seem roughly correct after the changes you mentioned, the Z coordinates of the cameras are upside down. Does the result look like that on your side? or maybe I type something wrong?   Further, I need my cameras always face center, which makes yaw angle of camera coordinates w.r.t. world coordinates changes along the route, so it shouldn't be fixed to 0.5*pi(?) Does that make sense to you? or do I have some misconception here?